# Desktop application in Windows Store style

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

is there any support for developing **Desktop** applications in **Metro** style (similar to Microsoft Zune) in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can't (out of the box). What you can do is use WPF with a library that implements Metro style for desktop apps like :

- [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)

  [image]
- [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/)

  [image]
- [APEX](http://apex.codeplex.com/) (screenshot from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408211/A-Zune-Style-Application-Template-for-WPF-and-Silv))

  [image]
- [Metro Toolkit](http://metrotoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Or rolling your own by customizing the WPF controls (Templates).

Answer (score 3):

Found another one

http://mui.codeplex.com

[image: metro ui]

it comes with controls, and looks like it is being actively developed on :)